# useEffect hook doesn't trigger on change in dependency (Object Type from useContext)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I am using the `useContext` hook to manage the theme in the project.

Here's how the `ThemeContext.js` file looks like :

```js
"use client";

import { createContext, useState } from "react";

let themes = {
    1: {
        // Dark Theme Values
    },
    0: {
        // Light Theme Values
    },
};

const ThemeContext = createContext({
    theme: themes[1],
    setTheme: () => {},
    toggleTheme: () => {},
});

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(themes[1]);

    function toggleTheme() {
        setTheme(theme.val === 1 ? themes[0] : themes[1]);
    }

    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider
            value={{
                theme,
                setTheme,
                toggleTheme,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
};

export { ThemeContext, ThemeProvider };
```

and now in `index.js`

```js
export default function Page() {
    const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(theme.val);
    }, [theme]);
    return (
        <ThemeProvider>
          // Content ✨       
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

The `useEffect` hook is only triggered once - when the page is mounted.

I want the `useEffect` hook to re-render the page every time the theme is toggled.

Comment: If you want your `useEffect` to work properly you have to wrap your `Page` in `ThemeProvider` not put it in the return of your `Page`. To use `useContext` you're supposed to be in the provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown all of your code, but I think you've wrapped your `child` around your `context` when you want to access the `context` from the `child`.

Try something like

```js
export default function Page() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider>
               <ChildComponent />
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

function ChildComponent () {
    const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(theme.val);
    }, [theme]);
    return (
    <>
        // Content ✨ 
    </>
    )
}
```

That way the `theme` will resolve from the context and be able to trigger the `useEffect`